# Как объединить две коллекции в Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Есть два контекста два данных.

```
 var o = (from a in dc.ozon select a);
 var v = (from a in dc.labirint select a);
```

Как мне их объединить данные и вывести в одну таблицу общую таблицу во вью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Контекст данных у Вас вроде один - `dc`. Вам нужно вывести список разных объектов(вы получаете коллекцию labirint `o` и коллекцию `v` ozon) в одну таблицу?

Comment: @koks-rs Да все верно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb311040.aspx) и создать коллекцию анонимных объктов.

```
var result = from ozon in dc.ozon
             join labirint in dc.labirint on ozon.isbn equals labirint.isbn 
             select new { Name = labirint.Name, book_id = labirint.book_id... };
```

Если анонимный тип не подходит то создайте модель в которой есть нужные свойсва и по такому же типа заполните

Можно подробнее почитать [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.7.php) на русском

Comment: а можно просто без equals, мне нужно без каких то условий вывести просто общие данные?

Comment: Не общие данные а просто все данные из обоих таблиц

Comment: @shatoidil, в этом случае вам нужен Full Outer Join, вместо обычного. Либо накрайняк просто создать список объектов List<Model> и туда добавить две ваши коллекции, где модель будет иметь свойста из двух таблиц

Comment: @koks-rs Если возможно то исправьте свой ответ, в этом была суть моего вопроса . Как объединить две коллекции просто, без каких-либо условий